# Minizinc no output

Tags: output, minizinc

Why would I get no output in MiniZinc? My program ends like this:

```
var int: Cost = sum (p in 1 .. nP) (Score [p]);
solve minimize Cost;
output ["Test"];
```

All I get is:
Running scheduler.mzn
Finished in 54msec

2/7/15 Happened again. Here is stripped down code:

```
array[1 .. 2] of var int: D; 
array[1 .. 2] of var int: F; 
array[1 .. 2] of var int: S; 
constraint forall (i in 1 .. 2) (S [i] = D [i] * F [i]); 
var int: Cost = 1; 
solve minimize Cost; 
output ["test"];
```

I get no output and no "UNSATISFIABLE".

Comment: What happens if you change the output section to:  output[show(Cost) ++ "\n"];

Comment: Seems I have made too many changes to reproduce the problem but what generally does it mean if MiniZinc fails to generate any output?

Comment: Are you sure that there's no message above this text, e.g. an error message? Also, are you running with "Run" in the MiniZinc tab? If the model is not satisfiable then the output should be "=====UNSATISFIABLE=====".

Comment: I think so but I'll try to save the code state next time it happens.

Comment: Perhaps you can publish the code (or send it to me), then I might detect if there's some strange thing...

Comment: See new code added to orig post.

Comment: When I'm running this via the terminal the output is correct: "test" and the two lines "----------" and "==========". You don't see any of these lines with "--" or "=="?

Comment: And when I'm running it in MiniZinc IDE (under Linux) then it also give the same (correct) result.

Comment: What happens when you add a new line after the output, e.g. output [ "test\n"] or output [ "test\r\n"] ? And are you sure there are not any more output above the final text?

Comment: Another thing: try to actually output an decision variable instead of just "test", e.g. output [show(D) ++ "\n" ++ show(F) ++ "\n" ++ show(S) ++ "\n"]; Also, in the Configuration tab, check the "Statistics" box to show solver statistics.

Comment: None of those suggestions change the output from: Compiling no output.mzn ... Running scheduler no output.mzn ... Finished in 57msec. I'm on Win 8.1.

Comment: Then you should report this to the developers: https://github.com/MiniZinc/MiniZincIDE/issues

Answer (score 0):

At least in MiniZinc 2.0.0 in console mode the example works:

```
minizinc example.mzn 
test
----------
==========
```

with example.mzn containing your code:

```
array[1 .. 2] of var int: D; 
array[1 .. 2] of var int: F; 
array[1 .. 2] of var int: S; 
constraint forall (i in 1 .. 2) (S [i] = D [i] * F [i]); 
var int: Cost = 1; 
solve minimize Cost; 
output ["test"];
```

so it displays "test" as expected.